# Proving $\int_{x}^{\alpha x} 1/y dy $ is constant if $\alpha$ is constant without logarithms

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose that $\alpha$ is constant.

We want to show that $$F(x) := \int_{x}^{\alpha x} \frac{1}{y}\; dy $$ is constant without the use of logarithms.

It is trivial if we use integrate $\frac{1}{y}$ however we must find an indirect approach.

My first intuition is to use the Fundamental Theorem to obtain the form,
$$F(\alpha x ) - F(x),$$ then I am not sure how to proceed, perhaps another approach would work.

Comment: $F$ is a logarithm, so you're kinda stuck with your idea I think. Can't write $F(\alpha x)=F(\alpha)+F(x)$

Comment: Set $y = e^u$ where $u$ is a new variable

Comment: @Physor that would change the bounds to logs. Not sure the depth "without logs" applies to that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First write (assuming $x>0$)
$$F(x)=\int_1^{\alpha x}\dfrac{1}{y}\,dy-\int_1^x\dfrac{1}{y}\,dy$$
Now we use the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\int_1^x g(y)\,dy\right)=g(x)$$
if $g$ is say continuous. Hence if $x>0$ and $\alpha>0$:
$$F'(x)=\alpha\dfrac{1}{\alpha x}-\dfrac{1}{x}=0$$
where used the chain rule to differentiate the first term. Since $F'$ is equally $0$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$ we see that $F$ is constant. You can do the same on $\mathbb{R}_-$ if you want to.

Note: this is how you would prove the log rule
$$\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$$
if $\ln$ is defined to be the primitive of $1/x$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\ln(1)=0$.